# Formatting java.time.Instant bean property in springboot 1.5.3 and jaxrs

Tags: spring-boot, serialization, jax-rs, objectmapper, java.time.instant

I'm using Jaxrs, to create Rest services with springboot 1.5.x. I have a bean with an Instant property. When I call my service instead of getting

```
{
 "startTime": {
        "epochSecond": 1517243670,
        "nano": 986000000
     }
 }
```

I would like to get an iso formatted date i.e. `{"startTime":"2018-01-29T17:51:05"}`

```
public class MyController{
 @GET
 @Path("/")
 public MyBean test();
  return new MyBean(Instant.now());  
}

public class MyBean{
 private Instant startTime;
}
```

I have added java-8-time dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-module-parameter-names</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

and tried several approaches, but none worked.

1. `@JsonFormat` annotation on the property

   `@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
   private Instant startTime;`
2. `ObjectMapper` inside the application configuration
       `@Bean
       @Primary
       public ObjectMapper objectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
       ObjectMapper objectMapper = builder.build();
       objectMapper.registerModule();
       objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, 
       false);
       return objectMapper;
      }`
3. with a @Provider

   ```
   public class ObjectMapperContextResolver implements 
   ContextResolver<ObjectMapper>{
   private final ObjectMapper MAPPER;

   public ObjectMapperContextResolver() {
       MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();
       SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
       MAPPER.registerModule(new JSR310Module());
       MAPPER.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
       module.addSerializer(Instant.class, new DateSerializer());
       module.addDeserializer(Instant.class, new DateDeserializer());
       MAPPER.registerModule(module);

       MAPPER.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
   }
   @Override
   public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
       return MAPPER;
   }
   ```
4. with custom Serialization/deserilization

   ```
   @JsonDeserialize(using=DateDeserializer.class)
   @JsonSerialize(using=DateSerializer.class)
   private Instant startTime;

   public class DateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Instant>{
    @Override
    public Instant deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext arg1)
       throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    return Instant.parse(jp.readValueAs(String.class));
    }
   }

   public class DateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Instant> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Instant value, JsonGenerator gen, 
    SerializerProvider sp) throws IOException {...}
   ```

I'm clearly missing something here.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I've got the same problem. It's ridiculous that something this simple is so complicated